# How to fix InputStream ReadTimeout error on FileUpload

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, email-attachments

**My setup**: asp.net mvc web app with a simple email form with fileUpload and send button.

The email is sent correctly and files are attached - **but the attachments are empty**.
Debugging the controller gives an **InputStream.ReadTimeout** in the expression `var myFiles = model.MyFiles;` (see below controller code).

**Model (only parts)**

```
public List<HttpPostedFileBase> MyFiles { get; set; }
public List<EmailAttachments> Attachments { get; set; }
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="files" type="file" aria-label="files" multiple="multiple" name="MyFiles">
</form>

<input type="button" class="btn k-button k-primary" id="send" value="Send" />
```

**Javascript**

```
 $(function () {

    $("#send").click(function () {
         var form = $("#data");
         var formData = new FormData(form[0]);

         var files = form.find("#files")[0].files;

         $.each(files, function() {
           var file = $(this);
           formData.append(file[0].name, file[0]);
         });

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: url,
             data: formData,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             success: function (response) {
                 alert("Success");
             },
             error: function (response) {
                 alert("Error");
             }
         });

    });
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendCompanyEmail(GeneralEmailViewModel model)
{
    ...
    var myFiles = model.MyFiles; // here occurs the ReadTimeout
    if (myFiles != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in myFiles)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(file.ContentLength);
                stream.Position = 0;
                attachements.Add(new EmailAttachments
                {
                    FileName = file.FileName,
                    ContentType = file.ContentType,
                    Stream = stream,
                });
            }
        }
    }
// ... code for sending the email ...
}
```

Any suggestions where the cause for the ReadTimeout could be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller code for building the attachments was faulty.
I found a working code:

```
    if (myFiles != null)
    {
        foreach (var file in myFiles)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(file.ContentLength);
                //stream.Position = 0;
                attachements.Add(new EmailAttachments
                {
                    FileName = file.FileName,
                    ContentType = file.ContentType,
                    Stream = file.InputStream
                });

            }
        }
    }
```

The **InputStream.ReadTimeout** message still can be read out when debugging the controller. Whether this is just a futile message of no consequence I could not figure out.

Anyway, the approach as outlined in my original post with the correction given above works properly for uploading files and converting them to email attachments.